# Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 on NUC D54250WYK

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Intel NUC D54250WYK.

Install went well, but after the reboot, I have the following message from the Intel boot agent:

```
Media test failure, check cable
Exiting Intel boot agent
Reboot and select proper boot device
or insert boot media in selected boot device
```

Went to setup, selected the ssd as primary boot device, but same result.

Is there a complete guide to install ubuntu on a Nuc haswell?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the yellow jumper for the BIOS to the next setting along and disable UEFI boot leaving the Legacy piece in place

You'll need the linux drivers from Intel and moprobe the kernel to get wired internet working.

Audio will not work over HDMI without a kernel > 3.10, so you may want to update the default one

Comment: Thanks, but it finally installed well, I just repeated the install and everything works, except the WIFI (Intel Centrino N6235), it works but connexion speed is about 6x slower than with an android phone tethered to the NUC. To solve this do I need to install Intel drivers and firmware updates for the NUC, or the Intel Linux drivers for the wifi card, or both ? (Or is it just this model of wifi card that gives bad reception ?)

Comment: Edit: Sleep mode does not work too, it wakes up 2 seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/02/linux-on-the-nuc-using-ubuntu-mint-fedora-and-the-steamos-beta/

They recommend renaming the EFI file to `/mnt/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to update the BIOS with intels latest BIOS-version first. I didn't had any problems to install 14.04 on my D54250WYK. They fixed their problems.

Comment: This worked great.  I had the problem, updated the bios, and then ubuntu popped up.

Answer (score 1):

I spent about a day unsuccessfully trying to install Ubuntu 13.10/12.04 in both UEFI and legacy BIOS mode. In UEFI mode, the hard drive is not detected and in legacy mode, the kernel hangs. I figured regardless of whether UEFI or legacy mode is used, there's going to be an extra step involved, so I decided to stick with UEFI mode.

The following link should help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Basically, I followed the web page and left Fast Boot and Intel Smart Response Technology disabled. The system booted the LiveUSB drive with secure boot enabled. Also, ensure that UEFI is checked/enabled in BIOS. Then install Ubuntu in UEFI mode (website has information on how to identify whether LiveUSB is booted with legacy or UEFI mode). After install, reboot using the LiveUSB drive and select "Try Ubuntu". Follow the instructions in the section, "Converting Ubuntu into EFI mode" to download/install the Boot-Repair utility and use it to separate the /boot/efi partition. Afterwards, the UEFI firmware was able to detect and boot Ubuntu 13.10 from the mSATA drive.

Comment: How is your network ? Do you use a wifi card ? Do you have full speed ?

Comment: I'm also using the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235. My router is G capable of 54Mb/s. My system is connected at 54Mb/s. My network seems to work fine.

Comment: Do you have any issue with sleep mode ?